# Codeigniter psd and ai mime type not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, mime-types, mime

i have visited some related question and try that step but still getting error when uploading file using `codeigniter`
`The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed` when trying to upload psd or ai files..
i have try something like that for allowed files type

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'psd|ai|gif|jpg|png|xlsx|xls|pdf|doc|docx';
```

i looked at `config/mimes.php` there value of psd is

```
'psd'   =>  'application/x-photoshop',
```

and my browser sends filetype `'application/octet-stream'`
i changed `mimes.php`

```
'psd'   =>  array('application/x-photoshop','application/octet-stream'),
```

but still same error
`The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed`

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for psd files

```
'psd'   =>  array('application/x-photoshop','application/octet-stream','image/vnd.adobe.photoshop'),
```

Answer (score 1):

**Extended psd extension**

**Change this(`application/config/mimes.php`)**

```
'psd'    =>    'application/x-photoshop',
```

**to this**
*Method 01 (uploading psd file)*

```
'psd'    =>    array('image/photoshop', 'image/x-photoshop', 'image/psd', 'application/photoshop', 'application/psd', 'zz-application/zz-winassoc-psd'),
```

**Or this**
*Method 02 (uploading cdr and psd files)*

```
'psd'    =>    array('application/x-photoshop','application/octet-stream'),
'cdr'   =>      array('application/octet-stream','application/x-zip-compressed','image/x-coreldraw'),
```